# Spline chart tooltip only snaps on x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have created a spline chart in highcharts, where the x-axis is datetime values, which do not necessarily align between series. Tooltips only appear to snap based on the horizontal position of the mouse, making it extremely awkward to see tooltips for certain points. Code below + fiddle link

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
    },
    series: [{
        "name": "series 1",
            "data": [
            [Date.parse("2014-12-16T10:41:30.000Z"), 62],
            [Date.parse("2015-01-16T10:41:30.000Z"), 64]
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "series 2",
            "data": [
            [Date.parse("2014-12-16T10:44:10.000Z"), 26],
            [Date.parse("2015-01-16T10:44:10.000Z"), 26]
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "series 3",
            "data": [
            [Date.parse("2014-12-16T10:44:17.000Z"), 104],
            [Date.parse("2015-01-16T10:44:17.000Z"), 104]
        ]
    }]
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNLu2/59/)

It is almost impossible to view the tooltips for 'series 2' with this data.

How can I make the tooltips snap based on distance to the points?

Comment: Try to use the newest master-branch which fix this issue. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qNLu2/62/

Comment: I see, further googling turned this up: [https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4128](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4128). If you want to add this an answer I will accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the newest [master-branch](http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js)